# When to use "When" & "Where" as conjunctions? Are they interchangeable in some cases?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I reached a level where I can speak English like a native speaker.
>
> We got to a point where we can agree.

In the previous sentences, the level and the point of view are not real places nor real time but the word "Where" is used. I think I got used to it because it's more common. I feel like when it comes to real time, the word **where** can also be used:

> I was there at the time **(Where - When)** the plane took off.
>
> I can't wait for the day **(Where - When)** my children graduate.
>
> You should have paid on the day **(Where - When)** the bill was
>   issued.
>
> The camera was recording at the moment **(Where - When)** the
>   expulsion happened.

Comment: Points and levels are real places in terms of knowledge. The others you list are not. Have you researched this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last four examples you provide, the use of 'when' would be correct. This is because each sentence is referencing a point in time. In the first two sentences you provide, 'where' is used because the speaker is referring to some position or state they are in, not a point in time.

Although you may see 'where' used in contexts such as those you provided in the last four examples, it is incorrect.

In conclusion: 'when' and 'where' are not interchangeable.